# Creating Threaded callbacks in XS

Tags: perl, multithreading, xs

EDIT: I have created a [ticket](http://sdlperl.ath.cx/projects/SDLPerl/ticket/63) for this which has data on an alternative to this way of doing things.

I have [updated the code](http://github.com/kthakore/SDL_perl/commit/e5aede73e86d54da85f621790492344de47f0580) in an attempt to use MY_CXT's callback as gcxt was not storing across threads. However this segfaults at ENTER.

```
#include "EXTERN.h"
#include "perl.h"
#include "XSUB.h"

#ifndef aTHX_
#define aTHX_
#endif

#ifdef USE_THREADS
#define HAVE_TLS_CONTEXT
#endif

/* For windows  */
#ifndef SDL_PERL_DEFINES_H
#define SDL_PERL_DEFINES_H

#ifdef HAVE_TLS_CONTEXT
PerlInterpreter *parent_perl = NULL;
extern PerlInterpreter *parent_perl;
#define GET_TLS_CONTEXT parent_perl =  PERL_GET_CONTEXT;
#define ENTER_TLS_CONTEXT \
        PerlInterpreter *current_perl = PERL_GET_CONTEXT; \
            PERL_SET_CONTEXT(parent_perl); { \
                                PerlInterpreter *my_perl = parent_perl;
#define LEAVE_TLS_CONTEXT \
                                        } PERL_SET_CONTEXT(current_perl);
#else
#define GET_TLS_CONTEXT         /* TLS context not enabled */
#define ENTER_TLS_CONTEXT       /* TLS context not enabled */
#define LEAVE_TLS_CONTEXT       /* TLS context not enabled */
#endif

#endif


#include <SDL.h>

#define MY_CXT_KEY "SDL::Time::_guts" XS_VERSION 


 typedef struct {
 void* data;
 SV* callback;
 Uint32 retval;
 } my_cxt_t;

static my_cxt_t gcxt;

START_MY_CXT 


static Uint32 add_timer_cb ( Uint32 interval, void* param )
{

        ENTER_TLS_CONTEXT
        dMY_CXT;
        dSP;
        int back;
        ENTER; //SEGFAULTS RIGHT HERE!
        SAVETMPS;
        PUSHMARK(SP);
        XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(interval)));
        PUTBACK;

        if (0 != (back = call_sv(MY_CXT.callback,G_SCALAR))) {
        SPAGAIN;
        if (back != 1 ) Perl_croak (aTHX_ "Timer Callback failed!");
        MY_CXT.retval = POPi;     
        } else {
        Perl_croak(aTHX_ "Timer Callback failed!");
        }

        FREETMPS;
        LEAVE;

        LEAVE_TLS_CONTEXT
        dMY_CXT;
        return MY_CXT.retval;

}

MODULE = SDL::Time  PACKAGE = SDL::Time    PREFIX = time_

BOOT:
{
  MY_CXT_INIT;
}


SDL_TimerID
time_add_timer ( interval, cmd )
    Uint32 interval
    void *cmd
    PREINIT:
        dMY_CXT;
    CODE:
        MY_CXT.callback=cmd;    
        gcxt = MY_CXT;
        RETVAL = SDL_AddTimer(interval,add_timer_cb,(void *)cmd);    
    OUTPUT:
        RETVAL

void
CLONE(...)
  CODE:
    MY_CXT_CLONE;
```

This segfaults as soon as I go into ENTER for the callback.

```
use SDL;
use SDL::Time;

SDL::init(SDL_INIT_TIMER);
my $time = 0;
SDL::Timer::add_timer(100, sub { $time++; return $_[0]} );
sleep(10);
print "Never Prints";
```

Output is

```
$
```

it should be

```
$ Never Prints
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "sleep" between setting the timer and printing $time?

Comment: If your program doesn't block but simply jumps back to the shell, this seems like a hard crash or otherwise perl wouldn't totally get out of control. Try a debugging perl and running things within gdb.

Comment: Ok I am trying this but nothingmuch has given me a completely different idea. I have attached the ticket to this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have found a solution to this using Perl interpreter threads and threads::shared.  Please see these

[Time.xs](http://github.com/kthakore/SDL_perl/blob/redesign/src/Core/Time.xs)

Also here is an example of a script using this code.

[TestTimer.pl](http://scsys.co.uk:8001/37783)

Answer (score 4):

Quick comments:

- Do not use Perl structs (SV, AV, HV, ...) outside of the context of a Perl interpreter object. I.e. do not use it as C-level static data. It will blow up in a threading context. Trust me, I've been there.
- Check out the "Safely Storing Static Data in XS" section in the [perlxs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html) manpage.
- Some of that stuff you're doing looks rather non-public from the point of view of the perlapi. I'm not quite certain, though.

Answer (score 0):

$time needs to be a shared variable - otherwise perl works with separate copies of the variable.

Comment: um ... I have no clue what you are referring to. Care to put some code up?

Comment: Add sleep 200 at the end and see if you see any output.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of handling this is storing the data in the [PL_modglobal](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#PL_modglobal) hash. It's automatically tied to the current interpreter.